# ASP.NET MVC Can I have a loop always be running even when no one visits the website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, loops, asp.net-4.0

ASP.NET MVC Can I have a loop always be running even when no one visits the website?

Is it possible to make a loop run on the website even if no one is visiting.
I want to make a loop to check in a List for values that are higher than 30mins if so it will remove users from a list. But where should I put this loop?

I made my own login system and I used my own DLL for it now I want to add sessions so a session should expire.
I was thinking of making an agent that checks a list of DateTimes binded to the session ID's.
If the DateTime is longer away than 30mins then the Session ID will be removed and the user will have to relogin.

Comment: Why can't you do that when request comes in?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You mean in the on page load? Will the loop stay alive for long enough?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a windows service.

Comment: @gilly3 I made a login system for a website I made it using my own DLL but I want to add my own session system. but now I need to make sure a session can expire.

Comment: Than clearly [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) (which does almost exactly what you describe) is not the answer... and doing `list = list.Where(u=>u.NotHigherThan30Min)` before using `list` is not an answer too as it will not be complex enough... Just build "you own scheduler" too - fun and educational, just don't use whatever you build for real site.

Comment: I could also make a check function and call this on every page load.
Or is that a bad plan? Because then old sessions will stay in there til someone visits.

Comment: Just as an FYI, you don't want to use Session to manage logins if you care about security. Secondly, just set the session timeout to 30 minutes and you don't even have to worry about it.

Comment: In addition to @believe2014 answer, I'd suggest a more comprehensive treatment of the subject: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Oct/02/Use-IIS-Application-Initialization-for-keeping-ASPNET-Apps-alive

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make a loop run on the website even if no one is
>   visiting?

Yes, you can. Simply create an endless loop. Or create a timer. Be careful of thread starvation due to [IIS's thread pool limit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx):

> The IIS thread pool has a maximum thread count of 256.  This thread
>   pool is designed in such a way that it does not handle long running
>   tasks well.  The recommendation from the IIS team is to switch to
>   another thread if you’re going to do substantial work, such as done by
>   the ASP.NET ISAPI and/or ASP.NET when running in integrated mode on
>   IIS 7.  Otherwise you will tie up IIS threads and prevent IIS from
>   picking up completions from HTTP.sys.   So for this reason, ASP.NET
>   always returns a pending status to IIS, and calls QueueUserWorkItem to
>   post the request to the CLR ThreadPool.   In v2.0, 3.5, and 4.0,
>   ASP.NET initializes the CLR ThreadPool with 100 threads per processor
>   (that’s the default, this is configurable).  So on a dual-core server,
>   there will be a maximum of 200 threads in the pool.

It looks like what you are implementing is a state server:

> The State Service can run either on the same machine as the Web
>   application or on a dedicated server machine. Using the State Service
>   option is useful when you want out-of-process session state management
>   but do not want to have to install SQL Server on the machine hosting
>   the state.

Indeed, ASP .NET has a separate process (different than the worker process) to run this loop:

> Session state is then housed in a running process that is distinct
>   from the ASP.NET worker process. The StateServer mode depends on the
>   ASP.NET State Service to be up and running (this service is installed
>   when you install the .NET runtime). By default the service listens
>   over port 42424, although you can change that on a per-machine basis
>   by changing the value of the
>   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\Port
>   key in the registry.